# Unable to remove rows which have more than 2 NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which has NaN in it, I tried running df.dropna() the it drops all rows which have NaN value but when I try using df.dropna(thresh=2) then nothing happens ,no row gets deleted. Can someone please explain me why is this occurring.

This is how I have changed the values to NaN

:

`for col in df.columns:`
      `df.loc[df[col] == '?', col] = np.nan`

[It is the the pic with total number of rows and Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLwGN.png)

[second pic when I used `df.dropna()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJxJn.png)

[third pic is after using `df.dropna(thresh=2)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0sxG.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Maybe `NaN`s are string, first try `df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)` before your solution

Comment: Did you perform the in place change or perhaps missed assigning the resulting value?

Comment: @Jezrael They are not strings

Comment: Your second picture, which you claim is after dropna(), looks exactly the same as the first one (dataframe wise). Which is contrary to the statement in your first sentence at the top.

Comment: Also, a better way to get `NaN`s would be `df = df.replace('?', np.nan)`

Comment: @Chandan - it seems your NaNs are OK, is possible add some sample data (be free change `df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':[5,6,7,9],
    'b':[2,np.nan, 2,10],
    'c':[11,np.nan,np.nan,2],
    'd':[11,np.nan,np.nan,2]
})`) with expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, thresh works for integer values. it will respond if you have only integer value is there and rest are NaN and thresh should be greater than 1. eq.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'id':1,'name' : 'John'},
        {'id':2, 'name' : 'Aaron', 'phone':43242123213,'age':32},
        {'id':3, 'name':'alan' }
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

OUTPUT:
    age  id   name         phone
0   NaN   1   John           NaN
1  32.0   2  Aaron  4.324212e+10
2   NaN   3   Alan           NaN

>> df.dropna(thresh=2)
```

It will not work but if I remove the name 'Alan' at index 2, It will respond and delete 3rd row 3 as only integer value id left.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the name"? You can't delete a single cell. Perhaps you mean, set it to NaN?

Comment: @9769953. Yes, I mean to set it to NaN.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Because then, the last row has only *1* non-nan left. And with thresh=2, it means a row is *not* removed if there are *at least* 2 non-nans left. E.g., you can also set the 'id' in the last row to nan (i.e., 3, instead of 'Alan': `df.loc[2, 'id'] = np.nan`), and it will work as well. Hence, the explanation about integer values is incorrect. It appears a misunderstanding about what `thresh` means, and I think Mahendra's answer is the more correct one.

Comment: Ah, of course, got it. Yes, Mahendra's answer is correct and this one is wrong (despite OP's accepting it).

Comment: more, if we set Thresh=1, it will keep all records having at least a valid value(not NaN) and if any row has all NaN values(invalid values), it will delete it. if we set Thresh=2 then it will keep all records having 2 and more valid values.

Answer (score 2):

thresh=2 says the row must have at least 2 valid / non NaN values otherwise delete that row. 
In given screen shots there are 13 column. 
So,  to remove rows which have more than 2 Nan the thresh should be thresh = 11.
In this way Pandas will move all the rows where it finds more than 2 NaN

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks...That was helpful to me...I used thresh=7, which came up with the expected dropna...and without it specified the dropna was deleting a lot of rows.
Thank you!.